# ExtJS - blank Menu expanding with no items when other Menus expand

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I've ran into a weird bind while making an ExtJS 4 Web Application.

I have this panel with an hbox layout and 4 Menus inside. The first menu has no items, the next 3 contains a varying amount (3, 1, 1 respectively, for now). I was testing the functionality of my menus when I noticed that the first menu item expanded whenever the other menus expanded.

Here is my code:

```
{
    xtype: 'menu',
    flex: 1,
    floating: false,
    itemId: 'menuBtnHome',
    margin: '0 0 0 5',
    width: 120,
    collapsed: false,
    collapsible: false,
    title: 'Home'
},
{
    xtype: 'menu',
    flex: 1,
    margins: '0 0 0 5',
    border: false,
    floating: false,
    itemId: 'menuBtnContactUs',
    width: 120,
    fixed: true,
    collapseDirection: 'bottom',
    collapsed: true,
    collapsible: true,
    title: 'Contact Us',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            text: 'E-Mail'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            text: 'Customers'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            text: 'Technical'
        }
    ]
},
{
    xtype: 'menu',
    flex: 1,
    margins: '0 0 0 5',
    border: false,
    floating: false,
    itemId: 'menuBtnDiscuss',
    width: 120,
    fixed: true,
    collapseDirection: 'bottom',
    collapsed: true,
    collapsible: true,
    title: 'Discuss',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            text: 'Menu Item'
        }
    ]
},
{
    xtype: 'menu',
    flex: 1,
    margins: '0 0 0 5',
    border: false,
    floating: false,
    itemId: 'menuBtnShare',
    width: 120,
    fixed: true,
    collapseDirection: 'bottom',
    collapsed: true,
    collapsible: true,
    title: 'Share',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            text: 'Menu Item'
        }
    ]
}
```

When I expand the 2nd menu with 3 items, my 1st menu expands as well, same height as the 2nd menu - but with blank items. The same scenario happens with menu 3 and 4. I'm not sure as to why this happens.

I have removed the `collapsed`, `collapsible`, and `collapseDirection` properties of the 1st menu as I don't need them. The menu renders properly without the arrow.

If I place in those properties for the 1st Menu, the menu will render with the arrow (suggesting it's got menu items) but clicking it or anything won't do anything. Expanding the other menus won't affect it either.

I'm in a bit of a bind and I have 2 main questions to get out of it.

1. Am I just missing out on setting a property or anything that will "unentangle" my 1st menu with the other menus?
2. Is there a way to remove the arrow icon in the ExtJS with the help of CSS? I can live with setting the `collapse-` attributes on but I've got to rid of the arrow icon.

Comment: If flex: 1 is applied to all of them then that is what flex: 1 is used for - to take up the space available.

Comment: somehow, that worked and I don't know why.